# The size of one of my list copies is printing out incorrectly in my stack

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

To start, the max size of this list is 30 and the number of items in each list created is stored in num_items, which is incremented and decremented by push and pop methods i have elsewhere but i am wondering if i need to keep track of the num_items here as well. I will show the output i'm expecting along with the output i am getting:

[image]

I will now show the code that copies my stack:

```
void operator=(const Stack& s)
    {
        if (s.top == NULL)
            top = NULL;
        else
        {
            top = new Node;
            top->data = s.top->data;
            Node* newP = top;

                for(Node* curr = s.top->link; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link)
                {
                    if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
                    {
                    newP->link = new Node;
                    newP = newP->link;
                    newP->data = curr->data;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

The code that is supplying the output is:

```
Stack<int> s2(s1); // s2 declared as a copy of s1
    cout << "*declare s2 as a copy of s1 (stack s2(s1))\ns2=" << s2 << endl;
    cout << "s2.Size()=" << s2.Size() << endl;
    cout << "s2.IsEmpty()=" << ((s2.IsEmpty()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
    cout << "s2.IsFull()=" << ((s2.IsFull()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
    cout << "s2.Peek()=" << s2.Peek() << endl;
    cout << endl;
```

Edit:

After initializing `num_items = 0;` in the code i will show below

```
        void operator=(const Stack& s)
    {
        if (s.top == NULL)
            top = NULL;
        else
        {
            top = new Node;
            top->data = s.top->data;
            Node* newP = top;

                for(Node* curr = s.top->link; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link)
                {
                    num_items = 0;
                    if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
                    {
                    newP->link = new Node;
                    newP = newP->link;
                    newP->data = curr->data;
                    num_items++;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

The output i get for my size turns out to be 1, i will show the whole output again in an image:

[image]

Second Edit:

I have now modified my code to the following:

```
void operator=(const Stack& s)
    {
        if (s.top == NULL)
            top = NULL;
        else
        {
            top = new Node;
            top->data = s.top->data;
            Node* newP = top;
                num_items = 0;
                for(Node* curr = s.top->link; curr = NULL; curr = curr->link)

                {

                    if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
                    cout<< num_items;
                    {
                    newP->link = new Node;
                    newP = newP->link;
                    newP->data = curr->data;
                    ++num_items;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

with this though i my size only counts up to 9 instead of 10, i figure because my loop is skipping over 0 or "NULL" rather, but there must be a way to make it stop doing that.

Comment: First of all, thanks for a detailed question. Unfortunately we are missing a key component: what are the attributes of `Stack` and `Node` and what do their constructors look like (if any) ? My guess: you forget to initialize copy `num_items` in the copy constructor (or `operator=`), and thus it starts with a random value.

Comment: If you do `Stack<int> s2(s1)` or `Stack<int> s2=s1`, you are calling copy constructor instead of operator=. When you do `Stack<int> s2; .........; s2=s1;`, you are calling operator=.

Comment: @MatthieuM. i edited it a little bit to include the intialization of num_items in `operator=` but it doesn't continue to increment when the other elements are copied, Stack is my class and it's constructor looks like `Stack(const Stack& s) 
  {
   *this = s;
  }`
As for node i believe it's just a pointer, but i feel i may be wrong.

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: note: you reset `num_items` to `0` at each turn of the `for` loop because it's inside instead of being outside.

Comment: @Haozhun That piece of code was given by my instructor and i'm not allowed to modify that if i understand oyu correctly

Comment: @MatthieuM. When i move `num_items = 0;` out of the for loop it still gives me the output of the size being 1

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: do you know [ideone](http://ideone.com/) or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) ? Those are online compilers. You can set the language to C++, and create a minimal example, then compile it and run it. It would be great if you could reproduce your issue there, and then give a link to your failing program, so that we can have a chance to look at it and tweak it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. will i be able to use two different classes in there? because i have a main class implementing all of my functions in a different class

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: you can implement anything that can fit in a single source file, however it may require some massaging. The goal of the exercise though is for you to reduce the size of your program as much as possible whilst still observing the bug. Often times, just by reducing as much as possible, the bug will jump at you :) This is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): a Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example.

Comment: Actually all that's missing from the first version is num_items++ next to each new Node.

Comment: @laune would my newest edit be what you were talking about?

Comment: @MatthieuM. http://ideone.com/FZKVLh , that is actually all of the code i apologize for not following you directly i was just a bit confused on how i'd go about joining those two classes

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: your code does not compile though; the trick is to reverse the order of the two file: copy paste `Stack.cc` first, and then copy paste your `main` function, and you will be able to forego `#include "Stack.cc"` => see [http://ideone.com/o3n1fG](http://ideone.com/o3n1fG) *Amusingly, your code does work on ideone, I get a size of 9* ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM. i mean it does work yes, 0-9 is 10 elements but my instructor's code counts up to 10 and our output has to match his exactly, if i was to set `num_items = 1;` it'd statically change it and i don't think it'd flow well with the rest of the code

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: actually, I realized two things. You need to initialize `num_items` to `0` in the `if (s.top == NULL)` condition, and you should indeed initialize `num_items` to `1` before the `for` loop, because you create a node outside the loop. With that done, your `operator=` should be okay (regarding length); however you are leaking memory like crazy...

Comment: @MatthieuM. well dang lol, i'd like to thank you for sticking around and helping me out with this but for now i'm a little burnt out but definitely will continue working towards this during the day.

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: My pleasure, I played around trying to complete your assignment while running tests for work-related stuff ^^

Comment: @MatthieuM. i fixed my code to initialize num_items in the right places and my count was definitely fixed, but my instructor's code makes a 3rd stack as well, which prints all of the elements out backwards, i don't understand why the 1st and 2nd stack would print out fine and then reverse order all of a sudden

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: Well, you have to look at the operations involved. We know that `operator=` is correct, since `s2 = s1;` works just fine; however `s3` is initialized with `s3 = s3 + s1;` which also involves `operator+`. Now, if you look at your `operator+` [here](http://ideone.com/o3n1fG), you should realize it is *really* weird. 1/ Why do you do two copies (`t` is useless) ? 2/ When you pop from a stack and push into another, you reverse the order of elements. You have to find a better strategy.

Answer (score 1):

A single list is best copied while maintaining a Node** store pointing to the variable that needs to be set to the next Node*:

```
void operator=( const Stack& rhs ){ // or return Stack&
  // call this->clear() to avoid memory leak
  if( rhs.top == NULL ){ top = NULL; return /* *this */; }
  Node** store = &top;
  for( Node* curr = rhs.top; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link ){
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    num_items++;
    newNode->data = curr->data;
    *store = newNode;
    store = &newNode->link;
  }
  return /* *this */;
}
```

This assignment operator will produce a memory leak unless care is taken to remove any existing entries. Perhaps there's already a clear() method?

**Later:**
These constructors might be used:

```
Stack() : num_items(0), top(NULL) {}
Stack( const Stack& other ) {
  *this = other;
}
```

This clear method should be used where indicated:

```
void clear(){
  Node* curr = top;
  while( curr != NULL ){
    Node* next = curr->link;
    delete curr;
    curr = next;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code works for my 3rd copy! it gave back a size of 10 but for my 2nd copy it gave back a size of 300k+, i'm not very sure how this number came about

Comment: Check your constructor - it should set num_items to 0. Or do call clear().

Comment: The thing about this is that my signature for this method has to be `void operator=(const Stack &s)`, which confuses me on if i can actually use this

Comment: `Stack()
  {
   top = NULL;
   curr = NULL;
   num_items = 0;
  }

  Stack(const Stack& s)
  {
   *this = s;
  }`

If that is legible, these are the constructors that i am using now, well many wouldn't see the second one as a constructor but that's how it was taught to me in class.

Comment: operator= *should* follow the general pattern of being an expression returning the LHS (principle of least surprise). Constructors are OK either way. All clear now?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack<int> s2(s1);
```

This calls the default copy constructor and not the operator=. However, since your copy logic is implemented in the operator=, the nodes are never copied into s2.

You need to write a copy constructor and move the logic from operator= into it:

```
Stack(const Stack & other)
{
    // Copy other stack here
}
```

Comment: You can implement the copy constructor using *this = other, leave the code where it is, and thus keep operator=.